# Show all instances of a certain string

Tags: search, highlight

I use `*` and `#` for quick and basic typo checking.

If I type `AVeryLongVariableName`, I can put my cursor on the word, press `*` and see all the other places that word is used. I know I spelled it correctly. If nothing else is highlighted and the cursor does not move anywhere, I know I misspelled it.

I would like to do that for multiple words. For example, when I have identifiers `foo` and `bar` all over the place, I might want to look for `foo.bar` and not match `foo` or `bar` by themselves.

I use `/foo.bar` for this. Is there a more elegant way to maybe select `foo.bar` and show me all the places that string is matched, preferably a way I don't have to type the string?

Comment: BTW, maybe you simply want fuzzy search? look for the plugin leaderF. It supports preview of all options and regex search (exact)

Comment: leaderF looks cool but if I'm looking to make sure I spelled an expression correctly, I want the opposite of fuzzy. I need character-for-character precision.

Comment: LeaderF in regex mode does this. Regex is precise.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a code just for this.It uses the quickfix window to display all instances of a string or a search. `:MC string`, or select an instance of string and press `Y`, or `M<motion>`.

```
function! SpecialFind(type)
  let &selection = "inclusive"
    exec 'normal! `[v`]"xy'
    call Matches(@x)
endfunction

nnoremap M :set opfunc=SpecialFind<CR>g@

vnoremap Y "xy:call Matches(@x)<CR>

command! -nargs=1 MESC call Matches(<f-args>)
command! -nargs=1 MC call MatchesF(<f-args>)
command! -nargs=1 MW call MatchesF('\<'.<f-args>.'\>')
command! -nargs=1 M call MatchesF('\c'.<f-args>)

function! Matches(pat)
    let buffer=bufnr("") "current buffer number
    let b:lines=[]
    "the right way to escape!!
    execute ":%g/\\V" . escape(a:pat,'/\?') . "/let b:lines+=[{'bufnr':" . 'buffer' . ", 'lnum':" . "line('.')" . ", 'text': escape(getline('.'),'\"')}]"
    call setqflist(b:lines)
    copen
endfunction
function! MatchesF(pat)
    let buffer=bufnr("") "current buffer number
    let b:lines=[]
    "no escape!!
    execute ":%g/" . a:pat . "/let b:lines+=[{'bufnr':" . 'buffer' . ", 'lnum':" . "line('.')" . ", 'text': escape(getline('.'),'\"')}]"
    call setqflist(b:lines)
    copen
endfunction
```